# Why doesn't ReplaceAll work on Image?

Tags: replacement, image

`ReplaceAll` seems not to reach inside `Image`, and I don't see why it shouldn't. Here is an example. Create a black and white image with four pixels:

```
image = Image[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

The full form of `image` is:

```
Image[List[List[1.`, 0.`], List[0.`, 1.`]], "Real", Rule[ColorSpace, Automatic], Rule[Interleaving, None]]
```

The following line switches the pixels as desired:

```
Image[ImageData[image] /. n_?NumberQ -> 1 - n]
```

My question is, in the following usage, why doesn't `ReplaceAll` reach inside `Image` and accomplish the same?

```
image /. n_?NumberQ -> 1 - n
```